# RDS Aurora and EC2 Locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am hoping to use the Aurora RDS service but before I buy, I need to clarify some things.

My EC2 instance is on Singapore and Singapore doesn't have Aurora. So if I buy Aurora from North America or what ever  Will that affect my Database performance?

because I would need to connect to RDS Aurora every second. With heavy user access every second.

Any other solutions that can be used to fix this problem of EC2 in Singapore and Aurora in Another location?

Comment: Why are you coming all the way to North America if your EC2 instance is in Singapore? AWS RDS Aurora is available in Mumbai region and of course cross region will affect the performance. Migrate your EC2 to Mumbai Region and use Aurora there.

Comment: Right, you can consider move to India or Sydney, where Aurora is supported.

Answer (score 3):

Beside network latency penalty, you'll also be paying cross-region data transfer costs. I would recommend to stick to MySQL for now, and migrate to Aurora when it is available in your region. For a cross-region scenario you will not benefit from Aurora's performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for performance and in Singapore region itself. Maria DB can be a better option for you. It need a small or no change in application to connect. continue this till Aurora arrives in singapore.